# Using a selected value in another field in MARIADB

Tags: rounding, mariadb

I have query:

```
SELECT  busCode, address, current.position-1 as position, movingbus.bus as bus,
        current.linea as line, destination, current.paletta as 'end',
        previous.paletta as 'start', previous.lapseToNext, current.ident,
        movingbus.latitude, movingbus.longitude,
        SQRT(POW(movingbus.latitude-41.717149, 2) + 
             POW(movingbus.longitude-12.312499,2)) as distance, 
        ROUND(distance*80) as `time`,
        current.previous as previous
    FROM  striscie as current, striscie as previous, movingbus,
        linee, palette
    WHERE  palette.number=current.paletta
      AND  current.linea=line
      AND  current.previous=previous.ident
      AND  current.ident=movingbus.striscia
    HAVING  distance<0.01
```

in which I calculate a distant and then a time operating on the distance: the relative part being:

```
SQRT(POW(movingbus.latitude-41.717149,2)+
     POW(movingbus.longitude-12.312499,2)) as distance,
ROUND(distance*80) as `time`
```

Yet when I execute it, MariaDB reports error:

> Unknown column 'distance' in 'field list'

If I conversely substitute 'distance' in the 'time' filed with the full operation producing it a in:

```
SQRT(POW(movingbus.latitude-41.717149,2)+
     POW(movingbus.longitude-12.312499,2)) as distance,
ROUND(SQRT(POW(movingbus.latitude-41.717149,2)+
           POW(movingbus.longitude-12.312499,2))*80) as `time`
```

I get no error. But of course I get a very big and possibly inefficient query. How is it possible to use the field returned by a select as an argument on an operation in the same select?

Comment: Which `line` is this??  `AND  current.linea=line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:

```
@dist := SQRT(...) AS distance,
ROUND(@dist*80) as `time`,
```

Plan B:  Compute the distance (and many other values) in a subquery, then use `distance` twice in outer query.

Plan A is simple and efficient for *this* case.  If there were a `GROUP BY`, it might not work at all.

Plan B is not efficient in *this* case, but could lead to a big performance advantage by not having to carry a bunch of stuff around before getting to `distance<0.1`.  I discussed this an hour ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35905072/1766831  Using that technique make improve performance more than what you can get from Plan A.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: the query turns to:

```
SELECT  busCode, address, current.position-1 as position, movingbus.bus as bus,
    current.linea as line, destination, current.paletta as 'end',
    previous.paletta as 'start', previous.lapseToNext, current.ident,
    movingbus.latitude, movingbus.longitude,
    @dist := SQRT(POW(movingbus.latitude-41.717149, 2) + 
         POW(movingbus.longitude-12.312499,2)) as distance, 
    ROUND(@dist*80) as `time`,
    current.previous as previous
FROM  striscie as current, striscie as previous, movingbus,
    linee, palette
WHERE  palette.number=current.paletta
  AND  current.linea=line
  AND  current.previous=previous.ident
  AND  current.ident=movingbus.striscia
HAVING  distance<1
```

and it actually works, thank you very much.